# What does bitwise or mean in function default initialization?

Tags: javascript

Some code I have has

```
function x() {
    this.type = 'image' | 'file';
    // ...
}
```

What does the bitwise `or` mean? The function does not generate an error but I just don't understand the code.

Comment: it's probably just a bug and `||` was meant. But even then it seems just plain wrong.

Comment: Usually when that's done, it's with `||`; I've never seen this before

Comment: @JanDvorak That doesn't seem to make sense here, given that *both sides* are clearly defined. Using `||` will always resolve to `image`.

Comment: And this will resolve to zero, it makes no sense either way.

Comment: @OP Do you have more code relevant to the function? This isn't sufficient to have an idea of how the function works.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the bitwise or mean?

Well, it is a bitwise OR. Ask the programmer what it should mean - although it seems to be a mistake.

> So what does it do?

It converts both arguments to numbers (which will result in `NaN` for the two strings) and then to 32-bit integers (which will result in `0`), then it OR them to a zero. That will always happen, so it's equivalent to `this.type = 0;`.

> What was probably meant?

The "default" operator `||` might be common and similar, but it doesn't make sense to me in here (there is no parameter in the constructor, the operands are no variables). My guesses are:

- The `+` operator would concatenate the two strings and is next to the `|` key on some keyboards - yet using a single string literal instead would be more reasonable
- The operands were supposed to be numeric constants (variables? properties of something?), and the `type` property of the object represents a bitmask of various types.